# 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, view

This is my script in `C#`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
IF OBJECT_ID(N''RealEstate.vwContract'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
  DROP VIEW RealEstate.vwContract

CREATE VIEW RealEstate.vwContract
AS
  SELECT RealEstate.Contract.ID .... (Rest of Statement omitted for brevity)
```

The error shows up:

> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Please help me.

Comment: Don't you need a `GO` after dropping a view?

Comment: I tested this solution but it shows up:
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Comment: @Simin.D.Karbasi indeed, `GO` is a white lie introduced by tools like SSMS; `GO` is not part of the SQL language, but is used by some tools to split a single file into multiple commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into two scripts and run first

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N''RealEstate.vwContract'', N''V'') IS NOT NULL
   DROP VIEW RealEstate.vwContract
```

then the rest

Comment: if you do that then the `create view` is *still* not the first operation

Comment: @MarcGravell The way I'm interpreting this answer, the idea is `exec sp_executesql N'if ... drop view ...' exec sp_executesql N'create view ...'`. That works, even if the two `sp_executesql`s themselves are in the same batch. It functions the same way as what you've used in your answer.

Comment: @hvd that isn't what the answer says, though

Answer (score 5):

The message speaks for itself; the `create view` must be the first statement - but you can cheat. My create scripts (if I need to run them from ADO.NET, so without `GO`) tend to look a lot like:

```
if not exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name='SomeTable')
begin
    exec('create table SomeTable ....blah not shown');
    -- more to add indexing etc
end
if not exists(select 1 from sys.tables where name='SomeOtherTable')
begin
    exec('create table SomeOtherTable ....blah not shown');
    -- more to add indexing etc
end
```

You can do the same thing with `sys.views`. Perhaps, untested:

```
if exists (select 1 from sys.views where name = 'MyView')
    exec ('drop view MyView');
exec ('create view MyView ...blah not shown...');
```

Comment: Not the best way to my mind as no syntax check when it is edited.

Comment: @Artyom only one line skips the syntax check, and it has the advantage of being trivially re-runnable - which you should ideally be doing anyway while developing it.